# how do i use setters and getters in java

Tags: java, string, int, setter, getter

I am new to java and still have an issue with setters and getters. 
I dont really understand the set up of getters and setters. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
*This is the output i get:* 
your cards are four & jack 
fourjack

*This is the output im looking for:*
your cards are four & jack
14



String[] cards = {"ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king"};
String card1 = (cards[new Random().nextInt(cards.length)]);
String card2 = (cards[new Random().nextInt(cards.length)]);
System.out.println("your cards are " + card1() + " & "+ card2);
System.out.println(card1 + card2);
}
public static int getCard1() {
    return getCard1();
}

public static void setCard1(int card1) {
    Player.card1 = card1;
}   
public static int getCard2() {
    return getCard2();
}
**strong text**
public static void setCard2(int card2) {
    Player.card2 = card2;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the index number in the last part

```
String[] cards = {"ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king"};
int c1 = new Random().nextInt(cards.length);
int c2 = new Random().nextInt(cards.length);
String card1 = (cards[c1]);
String card2 = (cards[c2]);
System.out.println("your cards are " + card1 + " & "+ card2);

c1++;
if (c1>9) c1 = 10;
c2++;
if (c2>9) c2 = 10;

System.out.println(c1+c2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation is one of the fundamental mechanism of making the member variables in a class as private and providing access 
to these variable via public methods i.e setter and getter. If a field is declared as private, 
it cannot be accessed by anyone outside the class even not the sub-class, 
thereby hiding the fields within the class. For this reason, encapsulation is also referred to as "data hiding".

Here, in your example you have variables which you have used directly, but if you really want to use getter and setter then you need to generate/create them. I have changed your code and created separate class to implemented via getter and setter.

```
class Game {

  private String card1 ;
  private String card2 ;

  private int c1;
  private int c2; 

  String[] cards = {"ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king"}; 
  int len = cards.length;


    public  String getCard1(){
      return card1;
   }

    public  void setCard1(String cardName1){
      card1 = cardName1;
   }

    public  String getCard2(){
      return card2;
   }

    public void setCard2(String cardName2){
      card2 = cardName2;
   }

    public  int getC1(){
     setC1();
      return c1;
   }

    public void setC1(){
      c1 = new Random().nextInt(len);
   }


    public  int getC2(){
      setC2();
      return c2;
   }

    public void setC2(){
      c2 = new Random().nextInt(len);
   }


    public String getCards(int i) {
        return cards[--i];
    }
}
```

Now you can use these getter and setter in main class as below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class test
{


    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    Game game = new Game();
      //get random numbers
    int a1 = game.getC1();
    int a2 = game.getC2();    
    //get the array values
    game.setCard1(game.getCards(a1));
    game.setCard2(game.getCards(a2));

    System.out.println("Your cards are \n1: " + game.getCard1() + " \n2: "+ game.getCard2());
    //sum logic 
    if (a1>9) a1 = 10;
    if (a2>9) a2 = 10;
    //Output
    System.out.println("Sum of you cards is :");
    System.out.print(a1+a2);
    }
}
```

Thus, you can build your code with setters and getters which improves maintainability, flexibility and extensible of your code.

You can view complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/MaheshKapoor/bd833e4d5810ef99407e). You can run this code [here](http://ideone.com/CptxUT).